# Xfce panel config file is rewritten with old contents

Tags: xfce

Xfce panel is very nice, but the GUI configuration is tedious, especially if you want to replicate the same panel multiple times.

Because of that, I want to be able to manually edit the XML file defining the Xfce panel's settings. If I believe correctly, the file is located in `$HOME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml`. I am aware that `xfce4-panel` won't take configuration changes on the fly and it must be restarted. Additionally, I am also aware that the panel will write its current configuration to the aforementioned file before finishing. Thus, my workflow is the following:

```
$ xfce4-panel -q
$ ... # Edit config file
$ xfce4-panel
```

Surprisingly, when doing that, the panel not only gets its old configuration, but also overwrites the supposedly "config" file with the old values, discarding my edits.

The panel must be reading a different configuration from somewhere else, but apparently it's not a file. I strace'd the panel executable and I found no `open` calls of something that resembled a configuration file (just in case it's relevant, here are all the `open` calls for xfce4-panel: https://pastebin.com/eHdEATMV)

How can I manually edit Xfce's panel configuration file so changes take place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem: I wanted to copy the panel configuration from one machine to another, and it just didn't want to use the one I copied, but always used the old even though I logged out.

It turns out, even when logging out, the following process kept running under that user:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
```

I suppose this is where xfce stores its configuration at runtime. Since it kept running, it didn't see the change in the files and even overwrite it.

A bug about that is already reported it seems: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13445

Answer (score -2):

When a new user is created all configuration is copied from `/etc/skel`.

Just replace the desired file on this directory.